# turning magic quotes off in bitnami stack

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, bitnami, magic-quotes-gpc

I have `bitnami` stack on `EC2` instance, I want to turn `off magic quote`s, but in the `php.ini` I cant find the option to turn off.
I have seen how to turn off magic quotes through code but if I do

```
echo 'Value for '.get_magic_quotes_gpc();
```

It only echoes `Value for`
Any help in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_magic_quotes_gpc` returns a boolean `false` if it is off. do something like this:

```
echo 'Value for '. (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? "magic quotes is on" : "magic quotes is off");
```

As reply to your comment:

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) clearly states:

> Returns 0 if magic_quotes_gpc is off, 1 otherwise. Or always returns FALSE as of PHP 5.4.0.

so if you call that function you get either a true result (it is on) and print that it is on with above line of code or the other way around. It returns false for newer versions, because it is always off in those functions.

If you get the 'else', that means it returns a false condition, meaning it is of. I can't explain it more: if false, then off. simple as that :)

Comment: returns Value for magic quotes is off but that doesn't proves that it is turned off as it is going to else condition

Comment: It _does_ prove it is off: it goes to the 'else' because the function returns false. See the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php